# Automatic Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, mouse

I need help with mouse drag and drop. I would like to make something like mouse macro. You specify the XY coordinates of cursor and then drag something to another XY coordinates automatically. Is it possible?

I know how to simulate Mouse Click and Mouse Movement, but I am not sure with the Mouse Dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WM_MOUSEDOWN, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_MOUSEUP -- use Spy++ to view windows messages